# 3rd party application passing url parameters to SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

The 3rd party application is passing the parameter values as follows: `Parameters=Collapsed&Priority=P1%7cP2`.  It is using a `%7c` (which is a pipe) instead of passing the parameters the way `SSRS` is looking for them as follows: `Parameters=Collapsed&Priority=P1&Priority=P2`.  The parameter is multi select in `SSRS` and works in Report Builder just fine.  My where clause is using IN (@priority).

How can I get SSRS to use the parameter values that are being passed in the URL?

Comment: Here are the same 4 screen prints that I see. Hope this helps.  I don't know what else to change.http://imgur.com/RvfWlhKhttp://imgur.com/OTLnPSUhttp://imgur.com/T3kssBrhttp://imgur.com/RDvcyVT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't change the application to provide the correct multi-value parameter syntax (`...&Priority=Value1&Priority=Value2&Priority=Value3...`) you can set the value that is passed to your dataset in the Parameters section of the dataset properties to be the following expression:

`=split(Parameters!Priority.Value,"|")`

This will take the pipe delimited list and separate it into a list of items that can be passed to your SQL query and used with the `IN` function.

I have created a dummy report to demonstrate this:

**Parameter**
[image]

**Dataset**
[image]

**Dataset Properties**
[image]

**Report Result**
[image]

Comment: I added that to the parameter section of the dataset properties.  Now I am getting the error:  Conversion from type 'Object()' to type 'String' is not valid.  My IN function is (@priority).

Comment: @DSakulich  Try wrapping the whole thing in a `join`.  Answer edited to reflect this.

Comment: now my parameter section looks like =Join(Split(Parameters!Priority.Value,"|"),",") but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of what you are trying to your question.  This will help me, but also assist anyone else that may be able to provide an answer in my stead.

Comment: I have a multivalue parameter called priority.  In my dataset where clause it says priority IN (@priority).  In my dataset priority parameter expression it says Join(Split(Parameters!Priority.Value,"|"),",").  when I run the report I get 'The value expression for the query parameter '@Priority' contains an error.  Conversion from type 'Object()' to type 'String' is not valid. (rsRuntimeError in Expression).  Hope this provides more details.

Comment: Is there a way to force the dataset to use the values differently in the Where clause?  The database is SQL.

Comment: @DSakulich  Without you posting screenshots of your set up there is little more I can do for you beside the additional info in my answer above.  Turns out I was right the first time and you only need the `split` function.  If this doesn't work for you, your error is probably coming from somewhere else.

Comment: This is my report dataset http://imgur.com/eQG2N3v.  This is my parameter dataset http://imgur.com/dGZioGv  I have set up my parameter like yours.  Not sure what to change my report dataset to.

Comment: @DSakulich Until you post screenshots of the exact windows I have, I cannot help you.

Comment: The best I can do is the link that will open the screenshots.  Does this help?

Comment: @DSakulich No.  You have given me two screenshots that in no way show me how your parameter data gets into your dataset for query filtering.  If you can't replicate my images, I cannot help you.

Comment: Here are the screen shots that I think you said would help.

Comment: @DSakulich You have not told your `split` function that you want to split on the `|` character.  Your expression should be `=split(Parameters!Priority.Value,"|")`

Comment: @DSakulich  If that is the case, kindly accept the answer so others with the same problem know where to look.  I'm glad you got things working 